# Can an app have multiple google-services.json files?

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

I have an android sdk which requires the app using it to have google-services.json file in its project directory.

I am wondering what will happen if the app already has a `google-services.json`file from its implementation and is receiving FCMs from its own google developers console.

Can an app have multiple `google-services.json` file for the same flavor.
Can an app receive FCM's from two different google developers console account? or How can an app receive FCM's from two different google developers console?

I am just trying to explore ways as to how I can send FCM from my server to the app without making the app change its underlying design.

Downvoting must be accompanied with reason.

Answer (score -1):

If you have multiple flavors configured in your app is intende to say that you will create multiple apps with different package name, for example:

```
   flavorDimensions "mysite"
    productFlavors {
        elnorte {
            applicationId 'com.jorgesys.creatorhdplayer'
            manifestPlaceholders = [appName: "Creator hd player"]
            dimension "mysite"
        }
        reforma {
            applicationId 'com.jorgesys.creatorhdfree'
            manifestPlaceholders = [appName: "Creator hd free"]
            dimension "mysite"
        }
        mural {
            applicationId 'com.jorgesys.creatorhd'
            manifestPlaceholders = [appName: "Creator hd"]
            dimension "mysite"
        }
    }
```

therefore you need to add diferent `google-services.json` files in your proyect for every application that needs google play services :

[image]

**The `google-services.json` file is related to the package name so you just need one file for every application. The same if you have only one flavor configured (one application)**

Comment: Thanks for your answer but my questions is related to one flavor only. Please see my edited question.

Comment: @Kanika at the end of my answer "The google-services.json file is related to the package name so you just need one file for every application. The same if you have only one flavor configured (one application)"

Comment: oh, so if I generate google-services.gson file from 2 different google developers console accounts using same sHA-1 value and package name, will they be same?